# Starting Activity from an instance of non-activity class

Tags: android-intent, android-activity

I've two activity classes : **QuestionActivity** and **ReportCard**. I have one different non-activity class SummationClass.class. This Summation class is called on onCreate() of QuestionActivity.

```
SummationClass s=newSummationClass(100,400,textViewProblem,buttonOptionOne,buttonOptionTwo,buttonOptionThree, buttonOptionFour,buttonSolve);
s.summationFunction();
```

this summationFunction() is a public void method which simply loads some Button values and TextView values in QuestionActivity layout file.

Now I want to start the activity ReportCard from a loop termination in summationFunction();
The problem i'm getting here is access specifier problem while creating the Intent within the summationClass() method.

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(QuestionActivity.this,ReportCard.class);
```

The error is :"**No enclosing instance of the type QuestionActivity is accessible in this scope**"

How can set the appropriate context for the instance to start the ReportCard activity? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the Context to SummationClass before running the function, or you can call

```
getApplicationContext();
or
getBaseContext();
```

Comment: Thank you Losiowaty. But both of getApplicationContext(); and getBaseContext() are giving the error inside summationFunction(). Its saying "The method getBaseContext() is undefined for the SummationClass"

Comment: It's propably beacuse my Android is a little bit rusty :/ If I find some time I will dig through my old code and find it, and for know I'd suggest passing the Context for proof-checking and testing :)

Comment: Thanks a ton in advance. Meanwhile i'm trying with your advise. :)